# Django model queryset using related names and managers

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-1.9

I have 4 models -

```
class Group(models.model):
    group_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class User(models.model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    grp = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class DesigType(models.model):
    desig_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Designation(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='desigs')
    desig_type = models.ForeignKey(DesigType, null=True, blank=True, related_name='desigs')
```

`Group` model holds groups of users. `User` holds records for each individual user. `DesigType` has information about "type of designation", like maybe manager, team lead etc. `Designation` stores the exact designation - for example, for manager `DesigType`, `Designation` might have project manager or account manager; similarly, for team lead `DesigType`, `Designation` might have front-end lead or back-end lead.

The UI currently shows a list of users under a group. I want to implement a search functionality according to `desig_name`. The UI sends me the `group_id` and the text entered by the end-user in the search box, and I have to return only those `User`s which have the corresponding `desig_name`.

I have already done the above, by using a `property` to return a list of `desig_name`s that a `User` has and checking whether the user input exists in the list.

This is a `property` under `User` -

```
@cached_property
def desig_types(self):
    desig_types = []
    for value in self.desigs.select_related('desig_type').values('desig_type__desig_name'):
        desig_types.append(value['desig_type__desig_name'])
    return desig_types
```

In my view I have a generic search function which takes any user filter to return the appropriate list of users.

```
group = Groups.objects.get(pk=grp_id)
_queryset = group.user_set.filter(**user_filter)
```

The above code works for filtering according to `contact_no` and `user_name`. For `contact_no`, `**user_filter` is `group.user_set.filter(contact_no=user_input)`, and for `user_name`, it's `group.user_set.filter(user_name=user_input)`. I want it to also work for filtering according to `desig_name`, but I couldn't figure out how to navigate through the relationships so I wrote the code below, that retrieves a list of `user_id`s which have the user inputted `desig_name`.

```
required_users = []
for user in group.user_set.all():
        user_desig_names = user.desig_types
        if user_input in user_desig_names:
            required_users.append(user.user_id)
return required_users
```

I then pass in the filter as `group.user_set.filter(user_id__in=required_users)`. But as you see, I have to have an additional code to get the `user_id`s, instead of directly using `**user_filter`, like with `user_name` or `contact_no`.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `group.user_set.filter(desigs__desig_type__name__icontains=user_input)`

Comment: The `Designation` model seems unnecessary. Django will automatically create a table for m2m relationships. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid, it worked. Actually there are a lot of other fields in `Designation` which I have ignored here. That's why the model seems redundant.